# Flask: How to update information on sqlite based on button input

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am getting:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'type' referenced before assignment

I am  stuck on the UPDATE function. However, I am able to INSERT AND RETRIEVE from DB Browser SQlite.

Currently, I am only able to retrieve the data but I cannot update the fields.

**App.py**

```
@app.route('/updaterec', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def updaterec():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        type = request.form['type']
        uploadre = request.form['uploadre']
        amt = request.form['amt']
        description = request.form['description']

    conn = sql.connect(db_path)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE items SET type = ?, uploadre = ?, amt = ?, description = ?\
                      WHERE id = ?",
            (type, uploadre, amt, description, id))

    conn.commit()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM  SubmitClaim")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()

    return render_template("editclaim.html", rows=rows)
```

**Editclaim.html**

```
<form action="{{ url_for('updaterec') }}" method="GET">
    
     <!-- Update -->
   <button type="submit" , class="cancel-button"name="update">Update</button>

    <!-- Generate all the claim content -->
    <table style=" font-family: arial, sans-serif;
       width: 70%;
       border: 1px solid black;
       margin: auto;
       margin-top: 100px;
       text-align: center;
       padding:20px;">


        <thead>

        <td>ClaimType</td>
        <td>Receipt</td>
        <td>ClaimAmount</td>
        <td>Is it above 1000?</td>
        <td>ClaimDescription</td>
        </thead>

        {% for row in rows %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{row['ClaimType']}}</td>
            <td>{{row['UploadReceipt']}}</td>
            <td>{{row['ClaimAmount']}}</td>
            <td>{{row['checkbox']}}</td>
            <td>{{row['ClaimDescription']}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>


</form>
```

If anyone knows, please drop a comment.

Comment: do you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't see button in HTML. How do you tyr to do it without button?

Comment: to update something you need its `ID` but you don't have it in `HTML` And you don't have `id = request.form['id']`

Comment: Oh yes let me update w the error msg and also the button

Comment: furas, the id is auto incremented so I just left it as NULL

Comment: `ID` is auto incremented in `INPUT` but you ask for `UPDATE` and in `UPDATE` you have to use correct `ID` which first you have to send to HTML and later you have to get from HTML when you press button. You can't `UPDATE` using `WHERE id = NULL`

Comment: How do I display the id in HTML? Furas

Comment: the same way as you display other elements `{{ row["id"] }}` but you should put it in `<input>` to send it back to flask when you press button. Other elements you should also put in other `<input>` to also send it back to flask.

Comment: if you display many items/rows on page then you should have many buttons - every row needs own button with own ID - or it may need ever row in separated `<form>` to send only selected row. I think you should find some tutorial because it seems you have to learn a lot.

Comment: as for me you should split it into two pages - first display table with all rows - `/list` - and with link to page for editing/updating single row - it could use url with ID - `/update/{{ID}}` - and this page `update` should get this ID use it to get data from database (using `SELECT ... WHERE id = ID`) and when you press button on this page then page `` should get it as `POST` and use `UPDATE ... WHERE id = ID`. You should see this in any tutorial for `Flask` but they may use module to simpler work database and simpler generate form in HTML.

Comment: Hi furas, do u have any skeleton codes?

Comment: Can anyone contact me thru telegram on how to solve this?

Comment: to build skeleton it would need to create some database and use two templates - and it need some work.

Comment: Hi furas, am I able to contact you through telegram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is full working template

page `LIST` show table with all rows in database.
And every row has button `EDIT` which open other page to edit only one row.
I added also page which can `ADD` and `DELETE` row.

In your version you had mixed LIST with EDIT. You tried to display all rows and also UPDATE single row. Doing this on one page would need to use separated `form` in every row.

---

I used `render_template_string` instead of `render_template` to keep all in one file - so everyone can fast copy code to one file and test it.

Code at start create TABLE in database and insert 10 fake rows. After first run you need to skip `generate_data()` because it will add another 10 rows in next execution.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string, redirect
import sqlite3 as sql

app = Flask(__name__)

DB_PATH = 'database.sqlite'

def create_database():
    conn = sql.connect(DB_PATH)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("""
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SubmitClaim (
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    type TEXT,
                    receipt TEXT, 
                    amount TEXT, 
                    description TEXT
                )                
                """)

    conn.commit()
    
    conn.close()

def generate_data():
    """Generate fake data. Use once."""
    conn = sql.connect(DB_PATH)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    for i in range(1, 11):
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO SubmitClaim (type, receipt, amount, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)""", 
                    (f"Type {i}", f"Receipt {i}", f"Amount {i}", f"Description {i}"))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/list">LIST</a>'
    
@app.route('/list')
def list():

    conn = sql.connect(DB_PATH)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM  SubmitClaim")
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    conn.close()

    #return render_template("list.html", rows=rows)
    return render_template_string(template_list, rows=rows)


@app.route('/edit/<int:number>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(number):

    conn = sql.connect(DB_PATH)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        item_id      = number
        item_type    = request.form['type']
        item_receipt = request.form['receipt']
        item_amount  = request.form['amount']
        item_description = request.form['description']
    
        cur.execute("UPDATE SubmitClaim SET type = ?, receipt = ?, amount = ?, description = ? WHERE id = ?",
                    (item_type, item_receipt, item_amount, item_description, item_id))
        conn.commit()
        
        return redirect('/list') 
        
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM SubmitClaim WHERE id = ?", (number,))
    item = cur.fetchone()
    
    conn.close()

    #return render_template("edit.html", item=item)
    return render_template_string(template_edit, item=item)

@app.route('/delete/<int:number>')
def delete(number):

    conn = sql.connect(DB_PATH)
    cur = conn.cursor()
        
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM SubmitClaim WHERE id = ?", (number,))

    conn.commit()
    
    conn.close()

    return redirect('/list') 

@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():

    conn = sql.connect(DB_PATH)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        item_type    = request.form['type']
        item_receipt = request.form['receipt']
        item_amount  = request.form['amount']
        item_description = request.form['description']
        
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO SubmitClaim (type, receipt, amount, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)""", 
                    (item_type, item_receipt, item_amount, item_description))
        conn.commit()
        
        return redirect('/list') 
        
    #return render_template("add.html", item=item)
    return render_template_string(template_add)

template_list = """
<h1>LIST</h1>
{% if rows %}
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>Receipt</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </thead>

    {% for row in rows %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
        <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
        <td>{{row[4]}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ url_for( "edit", number=row[0] ) }}">EDIT</a> | 
            <a href="{{ url_for( "delete", number=row[0] ) }}">DELETE</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% else %}
Empty</br>
{% endif %}
<a href="{{ url_for( "add" ) }}">ADD</a>
"""

template_add = """
<h1>ADD</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for( "add" ) }}">
    Type: <input name="type" value=""/></br>
    Receipt: <input name="receipt" value=""/></br>
    Amount: <input name="amount" value=""/></br>
    Description: <input name="description" value=""/></br>
    <button>UPDATE</button></br>
</form>
"""

template_edit = """
<h1>EDIT</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for( "edit", number=item[0] ) }}">
    Type: <input name="type" value="{{item[1]}}"/></br>
    Receipt: <input name="receipt" value="{{item[2]}}"/></br>
    Amount: <input name="amount" value="{{item[3]}}"/></br>
    Description: <input name="description" value="{{item[4]}}"/></br>
    <button>UPDATE</button></br>
</form>
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_database()
    generate_data()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you Furas, I'll try and get back to you again!

Comment: it is full code. It works for me. Do you run my version with database generated by code or code with some modifications? Do you have error message when you run my code with my database? Do you have error message when you run with modifications? If you try to run with your database then you have to modify for your database. And code needs `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` in database.

Comment: I copied from @app.route('/list') to   return render_template_string(template_edit, item=item). I then change the neccessary naming. I was received with this errors:
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: what url did you used in browser? I changed them to `/list` `/add` `/insert` `/edit/<number>` `/update/<number>`.  In my code I also create `/` to have some page at start when I use ulr without path - ie. `https://localhost`

Comment: I use addrec, viewrec. What should I add in my html?
<form action="{{ url_for('edit',int:number) }}" method="GET">
</form>

Comment: `url_for` needs function's name. If you have function `def addrec(...)` then you need `url_for("addrec")`. But you can always hardcoded urls and then you use values from `route("/addrec", ...)` - `action="/addrec"`,   `action="/viewrec/{{  number }}"`,

Comment: Hi furas, I have 1 more qns, in the UPDATE button in templete_edit, how do you transition to another page?

Comment: see in code `return redirect('/list') ` - it sends special response to browser with message to load other page - and browser load other page.

Comment: Thanks Furas, managed to solve everything!

Comment: Hi furas, how do you check if table is empty, it will not display the <thead> tags in html.
Currently, when I dont have any data in table, it will display display the thead section

Comment: you can put all tabel in `{% if rows %}... {% endif %}` or even with `{% else %}` to display message that table is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write sql. I think you should write a classmethod in your model.
Like that:
Your Model:

```
class MyModel(db.Model,CrudMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(256))

    @classmethod
    def create_admin_note(cls, id, name, description):
      try:
        model = MyModel()
        model.id = id
        model.name = name
        model.description = description

        db.session.add(model)
        db.session.commit()
      except exc.IntegrityError:
        db.session().rollback()
      return note



    @classmethod
    def update_model(cls, id, name, description):
        model = MyModel.get(cls.id == id)
        if model is not None:
          model.name = name
          model.description = description
          model.save() # 1
          return note
```

Yoour update func. is ready!

Viev:

```
@app.route('/updaterec', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def update_func()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.form['id']
        name = request.form['name']
        description = request.form['description']
    if id is not None and name is not None and description is not None:
       MyModel.update_mode(id,name,description)
    return redirect(url_for('your_view.template'))
```

explan #1:

```
class CrudMixin(object):
    def save(self):
      try:
          db.session.add(self)
          db.session.flush()
          db.session.commit()
          return self
      except IntegrityError:
          db.session.rollback()
          raise ApiException(e.__str__(), 201)
      except Exception as e:
          db.session.rollback()
          raise ApiException(e.__str__(), 201)
```

Comment: Hi! I couldnt use class as it is only for django framework tho

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works for you

```
 @app.route('/updaterec', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
 def updaterec():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        type = request.form['type']
        uploadre = request.form['uploadre']
        amt = request.form['amt']
        description = request.form['description']


    conn = None
    cursor = None

    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("host='enter your host' dbname='enter dbname' user='enter user' password='enter psw' ")

        cursor = conn.cursor()

        sql_query = "UPDATE items SET type = {0}, uploadre = {1}, amt = {2}, description = {3} WHERE id = {4}".format(type, uploadre, amt, description, id)

        cursor.execute(sql_query)

        cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM SubmitClaim')
        conn.commit()
        result = cursor.fetchall()  # fetchone()
        return render_template("editclaim.html", result=result)
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
    finally:
      cursor.close()
      conn.close()
```